# Running rake from cron

Tags: cron, whenever

I have started using the Whenever gem to schedule cron jobs with rails.

But sadly rake will not run, I traced the problem to the environment not being loaded.

The whenever gem generates scripts like:

```
/bin/bash -l -c '....
```

I managed to get it to work with

```
/bin/bash -i -c '...
```

[The change is -i (interactive) instead of -l (login)]

Based on the documents of  cron, their syntax is correct. Can anyone give a hint to why it might fail on Ubuntu 10.4 ?

Thanks

Comment: May be you had the same problem with me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410245/connection-refuse-when-sending-mail-with-cron-tab/13638766#13638766

Answer (score 1):

As you're using whenever gem, first of all, create a `:cron` task, which would be something like this:

```
task :cron => :environment do

    Rake::Task['db:your-development-env'].invoke

end
```

Then in your config/schedule.rb, setup your time of backup:

```
set :output, "/tmp/cron_log.log"
every 1.day, at: '1:00 am' do; rake 'cron'; end
```

To pass the settings to crontab:

```
whenever --update-crontab
```