# Connection refuse when sending mail with cron tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmail, cron, whenever

I'm doing a daily sending email task by using `whenever` gem. 
I created a rake task in RAKEFILE name coffee. Here is my task's code:

```
task :coffee => :environment  do
  ReservationBooksNotify.notify.deliver
  puts "hihi"
end
```

When I run this task in console
`rake coffee`, it worked! 
But when I create a schedule in schedule.rb to automatically sending mail every minute, I get an error

> hihi
>   rake aborted!
>   Connection refused - connect(2)

The error when I trace

```
rake coffee RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke coffee (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Invoke rails_admin:disable_initializer (first_time)
** Execute rails_admin:disable_initializer
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
** Execute environment
** Execute coffee
rake aborted!
Connection refused - connect(2)
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `open'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `tcp_socket'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:549:in `block in do_start'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:549:in `do_start'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:144:in `deliver!'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2034:in `do_delivery'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:229:in `block in deliver'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:415:in `block in deliver_mail'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:413:in `deliver_mail'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:229:in `deliver'
/home/duykhoa12t/Working/Bbookproject/Code/bbook/Rakefile:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/duykhoa12t/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => coffee
```

My schedule.rb (in /config)

```
set :output, "~/Working/whenever.log"

every 2.minutes do
  rake 'coffee'
end
```

I think my mailer configure has no problem because It worked when I send mail in controller and in console. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Were you able to send email from console on the same machine i.e. in production environment, or was it in development environment. Try starting console in production mode, and then executing `ReservationBooksNotify.notify.deliver`, and you may get a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I don't know why, I try `rake assets: precompile`, then restart server, everything works!